# What are all of the significant differences in JS between the big 5 browsers?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

First, let me preface this by saying that I'm looking for a solid list of the browser-specific differences in javascript, which could be either:

- When a browser handles a JS method, property, or function differently
- When a browser uses alternative/proprietary JS to accomplish the same or very similar task available via standard JS

So with the above in mind, if a browser offered a unique JS method that was not available via standard JS, that wouldn't really fit the list (unless the method later became standard and the original browser neglected to update to the standard).

I know there are lots of sources for these discrepancies, but I haven't found a solid "quirksmode" like list that I can turn to, so I'm hoping this question might become such a list.  If someone knows of a really good source already, by all means tell me and consider the question closed.

The other goal I have in mind is a way to measure various js frameworks; whether it's addressed and how well it actually handles it.

I can start off by naming the ones I know already:

1. General DOM event handling (what event property names are returned, what defines a click or change, etc)
2. AJAX Requests (Pre IE-7 has a totally different class for making calls)
3. XPATH Queries (Again, IE goes it's own way)
4. Document loading via AJAX (Firefox does not trigger some Document level events when a content changes are loaded via AJAX)

I know these are vague, but even a vague list all in one place is a good resource that can lead to deeper research elsewhere or expansion.

Finally, if there is a SX site that this question would be more appropriate, let me know, because I'd love to have a place to find more open-ended questions like this.

#### Update

I know this question is ambitious, but it's not subjective.  Maybe using "all" in the title makes it sound just plain unrealistic.  Let me refine my scope a bit:

The power of a good js framework like jquery is that it provides a means of writing code that all major browsers will treat the same, even if they don't use the same prototypes or differ in interpretation. The most obvious examples of this (that I know of) that jquery addresses well are:

1. Event Handling
2. Ajax Request and Response Handling

As far as I know, jquery does not have any methods that resolve/unify XPath requests (there's probably a plugin, but that's not the point).

It's these types of differences I have in mind.  As I said in the comments, differences so major that without a framework you end up writing two or more sets of the same basic code or differences so minor that you could lose a day debugging or refactoring because you have no way of knowing (without a handy list) that browser X treats a standard DOM property differently inside a `for` loop setup.

I also don't think there is as much need for listing a quirk in IE3, Safari 1.1, IE for Mac or Camino or elinks.  If you know some humdingers and want to provide it, it can't hurt, but don't mistake my use of "all" to mean "every last one, or the kid gets it!" I mean "all the big differences that a good framework should address" plus "all the differences a web developer should consider first when their code works in one browser but not another."

And as much as I appreciate that every browser is a special snowflake (or in the case of IE a "special" snowflake), I don't think this list is actually going to be that huge. If you really believe that I'm delusional and that the list goes on forever, prove me wrong by naming off a few and seeing how long the list gets, rather than just pushing back and thus giving me and anyone who hopes this question might help zilch.

Comment: Re: Voting to close as "not a real question". I know there isn't a "solution" to this question, but there are genuine, non-subjective answers. I was hesitant to post the question, but I'm hoping the objectivity of the responses will outweigh the open-ended-ness of the question.

Comment: "All of the differences"?? When you consider the number of major browsers and the different version numbers, that gets to be much more than `one` question.

Comment: @pseudosavant: Totally true, which is why I tried to define both the browser set and type of differences. Even then, the expectation of a list of "all" of anything, especially in web technologies, is unrealistic.  I'd like it if I could get a high-level list of common (or at least useful) contexts where there are either very major differences that require two sets of code like Ajax and IE, or very minor differences that will ruin your day tracking down (like Webkit treating properties differently in `for` loops).  Do you think setting the scope for browser version would help?

Comment: @pseudosavant I'm pretty sure my webkit example is bogus, but only because I can't recall the exact scenario. But it's along those lines and if I had a really awesome list of such quirks, I could look it up real quick for you.

Comment: I'm going to throw this over to programmers and see if fares better there.  Didn't realize it was the place for more subjective stuff.

Answer (score 3):

"All of the differences"? I'm not aware of a single resource, but have a look at [kangax's compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/).

And/or [Quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) - though you already mentioned that site.

Comment: quirksmode.org is one of my favorite sites and partial inspiration for the question. But it generally addresses DOM level differences, which is awesome but not inclusive.  I'll look at the kangax table to see if it's closer to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Cool list, but like quirksmode, it's more about standard JS support, which is only part of the cross-browser js problem.  We need a list that also addresses browser-unique implementation and browser-unique interpretation. (I'm always pleased when an item on quirksmode lists browser support as "incorrect", as that's oftentimes more destructive than not at all)

Comment: From the kangax page I linked to did you follow the link to http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/non-standard/

Comment: Busted! I totally didn't see the link. Let me see if that's what I have in mind.

Comment: the non-standard is a really cool list and I've bookmarked it for later use, but it seems more like a list of methods/techniques that are not part of the ECMA standard but are "standard" in at least a few browsers.  I didn't even realize that happened, so I'm glad you pointed me there, but it doesn't address (from what I can see) browser-specific non-standard code for techniques where standard code exists, nor does it address in the main table whether the standard is available in a given browser, but with non-standard results. Again, great site, but (on first glance) not for quirks.

Comment: To put it another way, the reason (I think) that jquery handles the more notorious differences with DOM traversing and DOM events is because those differences are readily available at sites like quirksmode.org.  Resig didn't Google "Dom Event Differences" and read ever page, nor did he and the developers read every line of code of SpiderMonkey. They looked at the lists and went from there. I'm looking for 1) the lists that got left out (meaning the really high level concepts where differences prevail), and the items that don't quite fit on any list and thus become the gremlins in the engine.

Comment: And for the record, I really wanted that site to fit the bill and if it had, you'd get the answer (I did upvote).  I'm not trying to be stubborn and force a list to start here just for fun.  If it's already out there, no need to recreate it here.